# Elasticsearch Parent/Child. How to query and filter on Parent and sort on Child field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, parent-child, parent

So far I can Filter Parents with Children and sort the response on a Child field, works like a charm. See bellow.

```
GET /parent_child_meta_poc/paren_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "inner_hits": {},
      "type": "most_read_doc",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "field_value_factor": {
                "factor": 1,
                "field": "read_count"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "avg"
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [Matts gist](https://gist.github.com/matthiasg/2b8748cfdf919ce77c3fd0438613cee6)

Example child mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "most_read_doc": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "paren_doc"
      },
      "properties": {
        "parent_uri": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "read_count": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the limitation comes in with requirements such as :

Give me all documents that fit this search criteria, return only documents that have children of "most_read_doc" and sort the returned parent documents on "most_read_doc.read_count"

Essentially I would like to:

1. query against the parent document.
2. return only the Parents results that have a child of "most_read_doc".
3. sorted on "most_read_doc.read_count".

Parent/Child seem to have fallen short on 1. With any sort of query resulting to "nested: QueryParsingException...No query registered for [functions]]" Exception.  No official Elasticsearch solution for this yet based on my search.  And struggling to find a working work around this thus so far...

*Other similar:*

- [Search child by parent field, elastic forum](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/search-child-by-parent-field-td3717937.html). 2012, not supported. -Kimchy
- [Sorting based on parent/child](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2917).  nested solution. not for my need, see bellow

**Note**: I can't use nested documents/merge the "read_count" with the parent as I have two systems applying updates to this index.

1. system ***x*** insert the parent documents to the index, overriding any previous doc with the given ID, no partial update capability here.
2. system ***y*** grab Google analytics meta data for most read doc and inserts a child document with association to the parent via the ID. This way system *x* can carry on inserting/replacement parent doc without affecting children.